# I have a Todo list. I added a key event. When enter is pressed on the name add the item seems to get added, but i see it disappear

Tags: javascript

I added a keypress to the addNameBtn. When i press enter the list adds to the list but it automatically deletes it. If i click the add button it works perfectly fine. I dont know why this is happening. i thought it was maybe the line of code inside the addNameBtn that states:
document.getElementById(`name-holder`).value = ""; I tried removing this to see if it would work but nothing. Also this is basically my first project and my 2nd post here so please i apologize if its messy. im learning to post on here. Thank you in advance.

the code to look at it starts after //Delete single// after that function the keypress it follows. thank you in advance

```js
`use strict`;

// const plcHolder = document.querySelector("#placheholder");
const btnAdd = document.querySelector(".add-btn");
const btnRan = document.querySelector(".ran-btn");
const btnDeleteAll = document.getElementById("delete");
const namesBtn = document.querySelector(".add-name");
let list = [];
let names = [];
// console.log(list);
   
//ADD TODOS FUNCTION///////////

btnAdd.addEventListener(`click`, function () {
  var plcHolder = document.getElementById("placeholder").value;

  if (plcHolder === "") {
    alert(`Please type a todo`);
  } else {
    var getParent = document.querySelector(".ul-list-container");
    var listTodo = document.createElement("li");
    listTodo.textContent = plcHolder;
    // console.log(plcHolder);
    listTodo.className = "text list-todos flexbox-space";
    list.push(plcHolder);
    getParent.appendChild(listTodo);
    
    document.getElementById("placeholder").value = "";
  }
});
////// DELETEALL FUNCTION

const deleteAll = function () {
  var getParent = document.querySelector(".ul-list-container");
  // var listTodo = document.createElement("li");
  if (list.length > 0) {
    list.length = [];
    while (getParent.firstChild) {
      getParent.removeChild(getParent.firstChild);
    }
  }
};
btnDeleteAll.addEventListener(`click`, deleteAll);

/// DELETE Single //

const addNameBtn = function () {
  var namePlcHolder = document.querySelector(`.name-placeholder`).value;

  if (namePlcHolder === "") {
    console.log(alert(`Please type a name`));
  } else {
    const getUlNames = document.querySelector(`.names`);
    const createDiv = document.createElement("div");
    createDiv.className = "name-container";
    const createLiName = document.createElement(`li`);
    createLiName.className = "text list-todos";
    document.getElementById(`name-holder`).value = "";
    const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 490 500");
    svg.setAttribute("class", "bin");

    const path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    path.setAttribute(
      "d",
      "M135.2 17.7L128 32H32C14.3 32 0 46.3 0 64S14.3 96 32 96H416c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32H320l-7.2-14.3C307.4 6.8 296.3 0 284.2 0H163.8c-12.1 0-23.2 6.8-28.6 17.7zM416 128H32L53.2 467c1.6 25.3 22.6 45 47.9 45H346.9c25.3 0 46.3-19.7 47.9-45L416 128z"
    );
    svg.appendChild(path);

    // createElem.src =
    const createDelete = document.createElement(`button`);
    // createDelete.innerHTML = "a";
    createDelete.id = "bin-btn";
    getUlNames.appendChild(createDiv);
    createDiv.appendChild(createDelete);
    createDelete.appendChild(svg);
    createLiName.textContent = namePlcHolder;
    names.push(namePlcHolder);
    var childre = getUlNames.appendChild(createLiName);
    // console.log(createLiName, names); // turn this one to see the whole line created with text content
    createDiv.appendChild(childre);

    // var getBin = document.getElementsByClassName("bin-btn");

    createDelete.addEventListener("click", function () {
      createDiv.remove();
      // const index = names.indexOf(names);
    });
  }
};

const nameEnter = document.querySelector(".name-placeholder");
nameEnter.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    addNameBtn();
  }
});

const random = function () {
  const ulList = document.getElementById("names-list");
  var temp;

  for (var i = names.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
   
    if (names[randomNumber] !== undefined) {
      temp = names[randomNumber];
      const t = (names[randomNumber] = names[i - 1]);
     
      names[i - 1] = temp;

      for (var i = ulList.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        ulList.appendChild(ulList.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * i)]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return names;
};
btnRan.addEventListener("click", random);

namesBtn.addEventListener("click", addNameBtn);

// const idPlaceHolder = document
//   .getElementById("placeholder")
//   .addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
//     if (e.code === "Enter") {
//       addNameBtn();
//     }
//   });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(237, 250, 250);
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 570px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#text {
  font-size: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.btn {
  margin: 1px 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: rgba(122, 200, 236, 0.839);
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.add-name {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.ul-list-container {
  color: aliceblue;

  text-decoration: underline;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}

#placeholder {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.main-container {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.list-todos {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.list-flex {
}
.flexbox-space {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(125, 204, 241, 0.878);
}
.flex-container {
  padding-top: 5px;

  background-color: rgba(116, 156, 156, 0.157);

  border-radius: 8px;

  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: 230px auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(116, 108, 108, 0.434);
}

.name-list {
  display: flex;

  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  gap: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.name-label {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.name-placeholder {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 3px;
}

/* Single Name Delete btn */
.name-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.single-delete {
  font-size: 5px;
}

/* TRASHH ICON */
.bin {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
#bin-btn {
  height: 30px;

  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(116, 156, 156, 0.157);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
}
#bin-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#bin-btn:active {
  background-color: rgba(197, 213, 213, 0.403);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: red;
}
.right-flexbox {
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
      
  </head>
  <body>
      
      <div class="main-container" >
          <form class="form">
              <label class="text " id="text" type="text">Your List</label>
              <input
              type="text"
              id="placeholder"
              placeholder=" Type your chores here..">
            </input>
            <button type="button" class="btn add-btn">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn ran-btn">Randomize</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn del-btn" id="delete">Delete All</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- <form class="name-list"><label class="name-label">Names</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder=" Type names.." class="name-placeholder">
        <button type="button" class="btn add-name">Add</button>
    </form> -->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="left-flexbox ">
        <form class="name-list"><label class="name-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" Type names.." class="name-placeholder" id="name-holder">
            <button type="button" class="btn add-name">Add</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="names" id="names-list">
          
            <!-- <li class="text list-todos">Judi   </li>
            -->
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="right-flexbox">
          <div class="list-title">

            <p>Your List</p>
          </div>
        
      <div class="list-flex">
        <ul id='list-container'class="ul-list-container">
            <!-- <li class="text list-todos">shopping   </li> -->
           
        </ul>
      </div>
    <!-- <div>
        <ul class="ul-list-names">
            <li class="text list-names">: Leo</li>
        </ul>
    </div> -->
     </div>
</div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: submit buttons submit.  `createDelete.type="button";`

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example. It's not realistic to ask people to read through 300 lines of code to try to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: i dont fully understand epascarello, could you please give me more details. thank you : )

Comment: Enter key submits the form if it has only one input. Change keypress event handler to `if (e.key === "Enter") {  e.preventDefault();    addNameBtn();  }`. Refer: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/